# Displaying Averages Graphically on Seaborn Swarm Plots

Tags: python, seaborn, average, swarmplot

Let's say I have the following seaborn swarmplot:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

[image: swarmplot]

What is a simple way to display the average of each of these swarms on the plots, perhaps with a different symbol, such as an "X"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pandas' `groupby` to aggregate the means. And then `sns.scatterplot` to plot them.  For some reason, the scatterplot resets the view limits. You can save `xlim` and `ylim` before and reset them afterwards.  To have the scatterplot on top of the swarmplot, a zorder can be set (tried with Seaborn 0.11.1):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
df_means = tips.groupby("day")["total_bill"].agg("mean").reset_index()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
sns.scatterplot(x="day", y="total_bill", marker='X', color='black', s=100, zorder=3, ax=ax, legend=False, data=df_means)
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
plt.show()
```

[image: swarmplot with means]

PS: Another workaround to obtain the desired view limits, is first drawing the means (but with `zorder` at least 4) and afterwards the swarmplot:

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="day", y="total_bill", marker='X', color='black', s=100, zorder=4, legend=False, data=df_means)
sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ax=ax)
```

An alternative is to draw the swarmplot on top of a boxplot, as in the last example on the [swarmplot's manual page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html).

Comment: Thank you @JohanC. Any idea why using your exact code renders a white "X" for the Sunday swarmplot and black for all of the others? (I am also using Seaborn version 0.11.1)

Answer (score 1):

to get the average of values in python, you can do

```
def avg(arr): # arr is a list of values to get the average of
   return sum(arr) / len(arr)
```